# Pasar una variable de un Activity a una clase en Android

Tags: android-studio, clase, activity

Hola a todos como puedo pasar una variable a una clase en Android estoy trabajando con una libreria llamada Retrofit, la variable que quiero pasar se llama link4 y quiero pasarla a la clase RetroFitObjectAPI

Aca esta mi activity

```java
public class Preaprobado extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String link4;
    public Preaprobado(String link4){
        this.link4=link4;
    }
    public String getLink4(){
        return link4;
    }
    public void setLink4(String link4){
        this.link4=link4;
    }
    TextView txt1, txt2, txt3;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_preaprobado);
        txt1 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        txt2 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
        txt3 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text3);
        Intent intent1 = getIntent();
        String link4 = intent1.getStringExtra("NAME4");
        final TextView mtextView = findViewById(R.id.finaltextView);
        mtextView.setText(""+link4+"");
        getRetrofitObject();
 }
        public void getRetrofitObject(){

        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
        builder.scheme("https")
                .authority("valeria-serv-inf.herokuapp.com");
        String url = builder.build().toString();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
}
```

Aca esta mi clase

```java
package com.robotics.sistemaexpertocredito;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

/**
 * Created by Jaink on 24-08-2017.
 */

public interface RetrofitObjectAPI {
    Preaprobado g = new Preaprobado(String link4);


    @GET("link4")
    Call<model> getJsonObjectData();
}
```

Como puedo resolver este problema porfavor necesito que trasladar la variable link4

Answer (score 1):

Podrías solucionarlo creándote una clase "x", y definiendo una variable estática : `mi_link4`, para que luego hagas uso de esa variable estática en cualquier parte de tu código, simplemente llamando a la clase y utilizando el valor de la variable estática.

```
    public class Estatico {
        static  String mi_link4="";
         }

    //añadiendo valor a la variable estática en cualquier parte del código(o en otra clase):   
       Estatico.mi_link4="hola mundo";

    //Utilizando el valor de la variable en cualquier parte del código (o en otra clase): 

       String cadena=Estatico.mi_link4;
```

> No olvides importar la clase si la utilizas en otra clase o
>   directorio, Android studio te da la opción de importar la clase asi
>   que no creo que tengas problema con eso

Comment: Gracias amigo lo intentare ahora mismo

Comment: dale espero que te sirva.  